# UTC time showing wrong

Tags: mysql, utc-time

UTC time is showing incorrectly in mysql 5.1. currently, it is 9 AM

```
mysql> SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP, UTC_TIMESTAMP( );
+---------------------+---------------------+
| UTC_TIMESTAMP       | UTC_TIMESTAMP( )    |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2018-08-01 14:15:03 | 2018-08-01 14:15:03 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


SELECT current_timestamp dt1, utc_timestamp dt2, @@global.time_zone tz1, @@session.time_zone tz2;
+---------------------+---------------------+--------+--------+
| dt1                 | dt2                 | tz1    | tz2    |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------+--------+
| 2018-08-01 09:15:56 | 2018-08-01 14:15:56 | SYSTEM | SYSTEM |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: Well, now show OS timezone properties. I think it is `UTC-05:00`.

Comment: @Akina `CDT -0500`

Comment: If so I cannot understand what is a problem. UTC_TIMESTAMP reports you correct UTC time based on local time and CDT time deviation (minus 5 hours). If it is not correct - your local system timezone is not correct, edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, found the issue... ntpd service was not running in the server.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql` need the `mysql.timezone*` tables to be filled properly for explicit and implicit TZ conversions. They are not created and filled automatically on installation.

- Install fresh timezones on your host. Usually they are provided by `zoneinfo` package.
- Run `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /path/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql`

Refer the `mysql` manual for further information: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html